# how to call a func from another document/ Can't unwrap Optional.none

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

in Obj-c i had a nice tidy way of controlling the didSelectRow in my UISplitViewController 
i could easy add more buttons and write how they should work. meaning going to what storyboard and find there scene and show that to the user. In swift i'm have some difficulties doing the same thing.

here's what i had in Obj-c

```
-(void)initialSite:(int)viewId {
UIViewController *viewController;
switch (viewId) {
    case 0:{
        viewController = self.initital;
        NSString *star = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Velkommen til %@'s Bog",[data valueForKey:@"navn"]];
        self.navigationItem.title = star;}
        break;
    case 1:{
        viewController = self.startSide;
        NSString *start = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@'s Bog, start-side",[data valueForKey:@"navn"]];
        self.navigationItem.title = start;}
        break;
}
[self showChildViewController:viewController];

}

-(void)showChildViewController:(UIViewController*)content {
if(topController != content) {
    content.view.frame = [self.view bounds];
    content.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [content.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:content.view];
    content.view.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
    [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    topController = content;
}
}
```

Now in Swift i made the same-ish.. and i think it works.

```
    func initialSite(viewID:Int)
{
    var viewController : UIViewController?
    switch (viewID)
        {
    case 0:
        viewController = self.vc0
        let star = "Velkommen til \(data1)'s Bog"
        self.navigationItem.title = star
    case 1:
        viewController = self.vc1
        let star = "\(data1)'s Bog, start-side"
        self.navigationItem.title = star

    default:
        viewController = nil
        // do nothing
    }

    self.showChildViewController(viewController!)
}
func showChildViewController(content:UIViewController){
        if(topController != content) {
            content.view.frame = self.view.bounds
            content.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
            content.view.removeFromSuperview()
            self.view.addSubview(content.view)
            content.view.autoresizesSubviews = true
            content.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
            topController = content;
    }
}
```

this we call detailViewContainerController.swift.

In my hovedMenu.swift i need to call the func initialSite in didSelectRow
i tried working it around a little but always same answer "Can't unwrap Optional.none

```
var dvcc: detailViewContainerController!
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
    if let row = indexPath?.row {
        self.dvcc.initialSite(Int())
    }

}
```

Where is my Error ? i tried using stop points. and it stops at **self.dvcc.initialSite(Int()) <---** so something must be wrong with it. what i'm missing...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign a value to dvcc, so basically it is nil, and Swift fails to unwrap it.

Instead of `var dvcc: detailViewContainerController!`, you should try something like `var dvcc = detailViewContainerController()`.

Comment: gives me a error = detailViewContainerController is not constructible with ()

Comment: What are the init methods for detailViewContainerController ?

Comment: var dvcc: detailViewContainerController! <-- aint that it ?

Comment: No, this line is only equivalent to `detailViewContainerController * dvcc;` in objc, what you should do is the equivalent of `dvcc = [detailViewContainerController new]`. xCode should try autocomplete when you type `var dvcc = detailViewContainerController(`, no ?

Comment: nothin happens when i get to ( not even in playground

Comment: Do you even have a class named detailViewContainerController ?

Comment: in detailViewContainerController it has a class yes. but not in hovedMenu.swift i mean detailViewCaontainerController only has a class in its own document. it doesn't have a class in the hovedMenu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55440/discussion-between-sunder-and-kennyvb).